# If $f,g: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \ $ are differentiable with $f'(x)g(x) = g(x)f'(x)$, does there exist $c \in (0,1)$ such that $g(c) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Let $f,g: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $[0,1]$ with $f'(x)g(x)=f(x)g'(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Also, $f(0)=f(1)=0,\ f(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in (0,1),$ and $g(0) \neq 0$. Does there exist $c \in (0,1)$ such that $g(c) = 0$?

Now my prof has told me that such a $c$ does indeed exist. However after thinking about it, I get this contradiction:

Let $c \in (0,1)$ such that $g(c) = 0$. Define $h: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \  h(x)= \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$. Clearly, $h$ is differentiable so we get $h'(x) = 0$. Then $h$ is constant and since $g(c) = 0$, we have $h(x) = 0 \implies g(x) = 0$ on $(0,1)$. But $g(0) \neq 0$ so $g$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Where have I gone wrong? I feel as though I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited** The issue is that such functions don't exists. We can see this by slightly modifying your argument:

Indeed, as in your proof, define $h: (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ via $h(x)= \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$. Then, $h'(x)=0$ which implies that there exists a constant $C$ such that 
$$g(x)=C f(x) \forall x \in (0,1) \,.$$

But this is impossible, as the continuity of $f,g$ at $x=0$ implies
$$g(0)=\lim_{x \to 0^+} g(x)= \lim_{x \to 0^+} C f(x)= C \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)=C f(0)=0$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: But I've only defined $h$ on $(0,1)$?

Comment: It's defined on $[0,1).$

Comment: @NineteenNinetyNine Sorry missed that.. Check my edit.

Comment: @NineteenNinetyNine Note that there are two arguments, one showing that such $c$ exists, and the argument I originally posted showing that it doesn't. The only possibility then is that there is no such function.

Comment: @N.S. oh wow thanks!!